# Delphi sql search with both column

Tags: delphi, filtering, dbgrid

When i try to search both column, there is no filter. i want to list 5 and 30.05.2016 in dbgrid.

```
adoquery1.Close;
adoquery1.SQL.CLEAR;
adoquery1.SQL.Add('select * FROM Sheet11 ');
adoquery1.SQL.Add('where field9 like :blm and field12 like :blm1');
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('blm').Value:='5';
adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('blm1').Value:='30.05.2016';
adoquery1.Open;
```

Comment: What is the type of `field9`?

Answer (score 1):

So what is exactly the question there ?
Using parameters is right, one better not use string splicing due to all kinds of fragility and unexpected side effects - http://bobby-tables.com

And use proper data types!

```
adoquery1.SQL.Text := 'select * FROM Sheet11 ' +
                      'where ( field9 = :_p_field9 ) ' + 
                      '  and ( field12 = :_p_field12 )';
with adoquery1.Parameters do begin
   ParamByName('_p_field9').AsInteger := 5;
   ParamByName('_p_field12').AsDateTime := EncodeDate( 2016, 05, 30 );
end;
adoquery1.Open;
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine (now deleted).

Comment: @Dsm well, maybe it is, maybe it is not. I still don't get what even is the problem here?..

Comment: well your solution is certainly better than mine. As to what is the problem - my - I am not an expert in SQL, but don't date fields need to be surrounded by quotation marks? I would expect the original query to generate "select * from sheet11 where field9 like 5 and field 10 like 30.05.2016". But maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @Dsm, well the topicstarter did not word his specific problem, so we can only wander in the myst blindguessing. There are many POTENTIAL problems and which one bit his low parts - we can only guess unless he would come down to us and spill it out :-(

Comment: However with dates - yes, it should be presented as string literal, quoted, and here we go - different database engines would demand different quotation marks, different ad hoc patterns of string representation, and some of those would not have implicit auto-typecast, requiring explicit conversion string to date. that all CAN be his problem, or CAN be not it. We can only guess :-(

Answer (score 1):

You've got a pretty bad SQL error. `LIKE` does not work for any types other than strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, etc.). It does not work for numbers or dates. You're looking for `=` instead, for exact matches, or `BETWEEN` if you want something between two values.

This should work for you:

```
  adoquery1.Close;
  adoquery1.SQL.CLEAR;
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('select * FROM Sheet11 ');
  adoquery1.SQL.Add('where field9 = :blm and field12 = :blm1');
  adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('blm').Value:= 5; // Notice no quotes
  adoquery1.Parameters.ParamByName('blm1').Value:= '2016-05-30'; // Note no extra quotes
  adoquery1.Open;
```